# What approaches can one recommend for accelerating a massively (CPU) parallel program?

Tags: c++, mpi, gpgpu, hardware-acceleration, evolutionary-algorithm

My neuroevolution program (C++) is currently limited to small data sets, and I have projects for it that would (on my current workstation/cloud arrangement) take months to run. The biggest bottleneck is NOT the evaluation of the network or evolutionary processes; it is the size of the data sets. To obtain the fitness of a candidate network, it must be evaluated for EACH record in the set.

In a perfect world, I would have access to a cloud-based virtual machine instance with 1 core for each record in the 15,120-record Cover Type data set. However, the largest VMs I have found are 112-core. At present my program uses OpenMP to parallelize the for-loop implementing the evaluation of all records. The speedup is equal to the number of cores. The crossover/mutation is serial, but could easily be parallelized for the evaluation of each individual (100-10,000 of them).

The biggest problem is the way the network had to be implemented. Addressing the network directly from this structure.

```
    struct DNA {
        vector<int> sizes;
        vector<Function> types;
        vector<vector<double>> biases;
        vector<vector<vector<double>>> weights;
    };
```

GPU acceleration appears to be impossible. The program's structures must be made of multi-dimensional data types of sizes that can differ (not every layer is the same size). I selected STL vectors... THEN realized that kernels cannot be passed or address these. Standard operations (vector/matrix) would require data conversion, transfer, run, and conversion back. It simply isn't viable.

MPI. I have condsidered this, recently, and it would appear to be viable for the purposes of evaluating the fitness of each individual. If evaluating each takes more that a couple of seconds (which is a near-certainty), I can imagine this approach being the best way forward. However, I am considering 3 possibilities for how to procced:

1. Initialize a "master" cloud instance, and use it to launch 100-10,000 smaller instances. Each would have a copy of the data set in-memory, and would need to be deleted once the program found a solution.
2. SBCs, with their low costs and increasing specifications could permit the construction of a small home computing cluster, eliminating any security concerns with the cloud and giving me more control over the hardware.
3. I have no idea what I'm doing, it is impossible to breed larger neural networks (practically) without GPU acceleration, I failed to understand that the "thrust" library could allow vector-based code to run on a GPU, and I haven't done my homework.

Comment: I don't know anything about neuroevolution, but let me ask a more generic question about your approach.  What have you done to profile your existing code running on a single core. (Have you used any profiling tools?)

Comment: You can pass the vector data just like regular arrays. Not sure why that should be a stumbling block.

Comment: So much that doesn't make sense.  Large data sets are not a bottleneck; the operation you perform on them can be.  You "found" 112 ... what?  VMs?  records?  The datasets must be variable size because oops or for reasons?  You claim to be getting linear speedup in cores; that is surprising.  Usually core count gives slightly sublinear speedup due to other resources being in contention, even if just memory bandwidth or allocations.

Comment: Have you looked into thrust library? https://github.com/thrust/thrust it's focused on providing STL library functionality and GPU acceleration.

Comment: you are describing an embarrassingly parallel computation (e.g. one core per record, all computations are independent) but you chose to parallelize the evaluation of a single record. The rule of thumb is to parallelize at the highest level requiring the less communications. If you can evaluate records independently, then you do not even need MPI nor OpenMP, and a creative launch script would do the job (and scale to any size of cluster)

Comment: Yakk, I have edited the question with the following clarifications. Size of the largest virtual machine I could find: 112-cores. Vectors of the network must be variable-size. The neural net can evaluate a single record in nearly no time. It is the evaluation for ALL of them that bottlenecks the program. When done in parallel, the increase appears near-linear (1 record, 1 network, 1 error written to 1 record of a vector).

Comment: Gilles, what are you referring to when you say "creative launch script?" Are you trying to say "launch 1 copy of the program for each network?" Neuroevolution doesn't work that way. Each network is a member of a population, and each member must be evaluated for fitness before a central algorithm decides which to keep, breed, or delete. Pardon me, if I do not understand what you are trying to say. Could you elaborate?

Comment: "access to a cloud-based virtual machine instance with 1 core for each record" suggests records can be evaluated independently. If this is your bottleneck, then a simple approach is to evaluate 1 record per process in as many processes as possible, dump the evaluation into a file, and then apply your central algorithm. With MPI, you could evaluate n records per task (assuming you will not get less cores than records) and then finally gather the data and apply the central algorithm. makes sense ?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at what you described, I do not think GPU acceleration is impossible. My favorite approach is OpenCL but even if you use CUDA, you can't easily use C++ STL for the purpose. But if you go through the hurdle of converting your C++ code to C data structures (i.e., `float`, `double`, or `int` and arrays of them, instead of `vector<>` types, and redefine your `vector<Function>` into more primitive types), leveraging the GPU should be easy, especially if your program is mostly matrix operations. But you may want to beware that GPU architecture is different from CPU. If your logic has a lot of branching (i.e., if-then-else structures), the performance in GPU would not be good.

Comment: The program cannot be implemented without a data type that can be sized in the z, y, and z directions, with each sub-dimension NOT needing to be the same size. So far as I understand, no form of array can accomplish this. I have tried sub-classes (network, layer, neuron), but I still need vectors to hold them inside of the object.

Comment: that's why it is a hurdle. Yes, C++ give you some convenience but it doesn't mean C is impossible. I am not familiar with your specific domain but I still believe it is possible. Without knowing exactly what your algorithm and data looks like, I cannot be very specific. One way to do the flexible size is to make use of additional array as indicator for the size of your sub-dimension.

Answer (score 0):

GPU is far more capable than you thought. All the memory in GPU is dynamically allocated, which means you can allocate as many memory as you want. If you want to specify different size for each thread, just simply store them in an array and use thread ID to index. Moreover, you can even store the network in shared memory and evaluate records over the threads to accelerate memory access. The most convenient way, as you mentioned, is to make use of thrust library. You don't need to understand how it is implemented if your aim is not study GPU. You neither need to worry about performance issue because it is optimized by professional GPU experts (many from Nvidia who build GPU). Thrust is designed very similar to STL, therefore it is easy to master if you are familiar with C++.